# To show $(n,n+1)=1$ for all $n>0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

To prove $(n,n+1)=1$ for all $n>0$

i have tried using induction. So finally i have $(k,k+1)=1$ and i have to prove $(k+1,k+2)=1$

Let $(k+1,k+2)=d$. So $d|(k+1)$. Also $1|(k+1)$. Since $1$ and $d$ are both greatest numbers to divide $k+1$ So $1=d$

is this correct

Comment: Why is $1$ greatest number to divide $k+1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work, since $1$ is not in fact the greatest number to divide $k+1$.  The simple solution is that $1=(n+1)-n$, which immediately implies $(n,n+1)=1$ since the gcd is the smallest positive integer you can obtain as a linear combination of the two numbers with (signed) integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need induction.

Hint:

If $d\mid n$ and $d\mid n+1$ then also $d\mid (n+1)-n=1$.

Comment: But what about my proof sir ?

Comment: That is not correct. You claim that $1$ is greatest number to divide $k+1$ but your induction hypothese only states that $1$ is the greatest number to divide $k+1$ **and** $k$.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Thanks

Comment: but can it be done using induction

Comment: I do not see a proper route to do it by induction.

Answer (score 2):

No, induction doesn't work.

What you can do is this:

$$(n,n+1)=(n, \quad1\cdot (n+1)-1\cdot n)=(n,1)=1$$